# Javascript: Is there a reason to do "if (!a || (a && a.a))"?

Tags: javascript, optimization, conditional-statements

Is there a special reason to do:

```
if (!options || (options && options.booleanCondition))
```

Instead of:

```
if (!options || options.booleanCondition)
```

I'm no javascript guru, so perhaps there's a special case or reason why the author of that code wrote it that way.

Comment: if (!a || a.a) seems reasonable to me, maybe i'm wrong?

Comment: Where have you seen this used?

Comment: Well... maybe if a is treated like a "variant", when it is assigned a value of "false" the condition will work so that it enter inside the if only if a is not a boolean.

Comment: @GregB in code written by a graphical designer. I thought that it was wrong and had too many checks, but I asked this question before because I don't know what weird stuff may happen with javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i don't see a reason to do

```
if (!options || (options && options.booleanCondition))
```

I'm no Guru but i'd stick to

```
if (!options || options.booleanCondition)
```

and save a check to the fact that options is true: in fact if `options` is not true the first condition is `true` and the second is never evaluated since it's an `or` condition.

That's what i think

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's using a getter. This is a rediculous example but it can be the reason:

```
var o = {};
var i = 0;

o.__defineGetter__('options', function() {
    return (i++) % 2 === 0 ? {booleanCondition: true} : null;
});

o.options; // Object first time
o.options; // null second time
```

This means:

```
if (!o.options || (o.options && o.options.booleanCondition))
```

`!o.options` is `false` (negating an object), but after that `o.options` is `null` (falsy) so then the check is mandatory.

Comment: As i wrote in my post, i think that if `o.options` is not true `!options` is true and so the second part of the or condition never gets evalued, but maybe i'm wrong

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti: In that case there is nothing fancy happening. It's getting interesting when `o.options` is thruthy because then the second check is done, and the question is whether it can be eliminated or not in that case.

Comment: Thank you, you show a very weird and interesting case, and since options is a simple object used as a map, I'll do the optimization.

Answer (score 0):

if options.booleanCondition can change, then yes. If options is false, then the If condition will be true. If options is true, and boolean.Condition is false, then the If condition will be false. If option is true, and boolean.Condition is true, then the If condition will be true.

**UPDATE**

Actually, I guess it wouldn't be needed - since your simplification would be (if !true or true) if options is true, so the result would be same as (if true or true).

Comment: If `options` is `false`, `null` or `undefined`, it cannot have a property `booleanCondition`. I assume `!options` should test whether the value is an object. But we could only know for sure if we knew the context...

Comment: @felix if `options` resolve to `false` the first condition of the or is true and the second never gets evalutated i think

Comment: @Matt: if `options` is true then the resultant expression is completely rely on the `booleanCondition`. so what's  your point

Comment: @Nicola: You are right.... I think all this options and false and true and ifs are confusing me ;)